# Problem reading from GPS

Tags: arduino-mega

Right now I am working on a project where I need to turn on four LEDs in sequence, 1100 before 12 am and 1010 after 12 am. I am using a GPS in this project and I want to access the time from the GPS. The problem is that I am not getting it. How to make it possible?

GPS module: RoyalTek 4216

CODE:

```
#include <NMEAGPS.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial gpsPort( 50, 52 );
#define gps_port Serial1
NMEAGPS gps;
gps_fix fix;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  gpsPort.begin(9600);
  for (int thisPin = 2; thisPin <= 13; thisPin++) {
    pinMode(thisPin, OUTPUT);
    int i=0;  
    long k;
  }
  for (int n = 22; n <= 52; n++) {
    pinMode(n, OUTPUT);
  }
}
// the loop routine runs over and over again forever:
void loop() {
  while (gps.available(gpsPort)) {
    gps_fix fix = gps.read();
    Serial.print(F("DATE:  "));
    if (fix.valid.date && fix.valid.time) {
      // Shift the date/time to local time
      NeoGPS::clock_t localSeconds;
      NeoGPS::time_t  localTime; {
        using namespace NeoGPS;
        localSeconds = (clock_t) fix.dateTime;
        localSeconds += 5 * SECONDS_PER_HOUR + 30 * SECONDS_PER_MINUTE;
        localTime = localSeconds;             
      }
      Serial.print( localTime.date);
      Serial.print( '/' );
      Serial.print( localTime.month);
      Serial.print( '/' );
      Serial.println( localTime.year);
      delay(500);
      Serial.print("\n*************************\n"); 
      {
        Serial.print( F("TIME:  "));
        Serial.print( localTime.hours );
        Serial.print( ':' );
        Serial.print( localTime.minutes );
        Serial.print( ':' );
        Serial.print( localTime.seconds );
        delay(500);
        Serial.print("\n");
        k=localTime.hours;
        int i=0;  
        long k;
        if (k>=0 &&  i==0) {
          digitalWrite(2, HIGH);   
          digitalWrite(3, HIGH);                 
          digitalWrite(4, HIGH);    
          digitalWrite(5, HIGH);
          delay(5000);
        } else {
          digitalWrite(2, LOW);   
          digitalWrite(3, LOW);                 
          digitalWrite(4, LOW);  
          digitalWrite(5, LOW);
          delay(5000); 
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Well, first you have to state your problem. What hardware are you using? What code did you write?

Comment: Guurav .  Please can you fill in the name of the GPS and board you are using (where the ??? are).  People need this information to be able to help you.  Also check the LED connections are correct, I guessed.  You have tagged mega and uno, please remove the one you are NOT using.

Comment: So what results are you getting? Your code isn't trying to do much with the LEDs, and you clearly need to read more about variable scopes because at first glance the way you declare the variable k is a wrong. Also avoid using single letter variables unless they only exist for a few lines, variable names should describe them not just be the first letter your fingers hit. Do you get any time displayed or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hate to have to say this and I always try not to, but your code is awful.  Firstly it doesn't compile, and I can say that without even trying because the errors are very obvious.  If you reply is that it does compile then you have posted the wrong code.

In Setup() you are setting loads of pins to output, why?  You are only using 4 pins, 2,3 4 and 5!

Having a `using namespace` line at the top of your code is bad enough, it negates the purposes of a namespace, but having it in the middle of you code is really bad.  Just type the extra few characters, it will save you a lot of grief in the long run.

Scoping chunks of code can be good, but not in this case, it makes the code harder to read.  It would be better if you wrote a function to factor the date time printing out, i.e.

```
void PrintDT (char* type, int a, int b, int c, char sep)
{
    Serial.print(type);
    Serial.print( a );
    Serial.print( sep );
    Serial.print( b );
    Serial.print( sep );
    Serial.println( c );
}
```

And then called it:

```
PrintDT(F("DATE:  "), localTime.date, localTime.month, local.year, '/');
PrintDT(F("TIME:  "), localTime.hours, localTime.minutes, localTime.seconds, ':');
```

The less lines of code you have the easier it is to spot bugs.

Here is why I said it won't compile:

```
    k=localTime.hours;

    int i=0;  
    long k;

    if (k>=0 &&  i==0)
```

You are assigning a value to k before you have declared it, but looking at setup it could be a copy and paste error, because you have similar lines up there.

Also assign meaningful names to your variables.  I'm guessing that k is the hours and i is meant to be minutes?  To be honest in this case I wouldn't use variables at all, just have this code

```
if (localTime.Hours >= 0 && localTime.Minutes == 0)
```

But that if statement doesn't do what you say you want to do at the top of the question.  When the time has any number of hours, including zero, and the minutes are zero.  According to you question you want

```
if (localTime.Hours == 0 && localTime.Minutes == 0)
```

But that means you will only see the lights on 1100 for 1 minute at midnight.

I hope that helps, There is nothing wrong with the process you are following, just some of the things you doing and the logic.  If it doesn't fix it, clarify what the exact error is and we'll see what we can do.

Comment: I have done my code and trust me it actually works. I know I did many common mistakes in my given code but reason is I have combined my two codes that's why. anyways sorry for that and thanks for help :-)

Answer (score 1):

So you don't know how to read the time from a GPS?  Is that the problem?

Since you haven't stated the make and model of GPS and microprocessor I can only give you generic information.

GPS output their data in ASCII format over a serial link usually operating at 9600 BAUD.  So you need to connect you microprocessor to the GPS using a secondary serial port (Not the serial port you upload through).  On something with only one serial port (Uno, ESP8266, etc) you need to use the SoftwareSerial library to do this.

Then read from the serial port as you would do normally and parse the string you read to extract the time portion of the message, this should be quite easy to spot.  Most GPS's pump out two different messages at regular intervals and so you need to filter the message you don't want.

Relying on just a GPS for time is a bad idea, because you will get periods where the azimuth of the satellites is to low and you won't get sufficient coverage.  I would also use an real time clock (RTC) and use the GPS to update the RTC periodically and source the time from the RTC.